# How to disable SELECT QUERY from auto-sorting the results

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

```
<?php
            $db = db_connect();
            $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM `order` INNER JOIN tb ON order.pc = tb.pc";
            $result_set =  mysqli_query($db, $SQLSELECT);
            foreach($result_set as $row) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['add1']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['add2']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['prov']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['pc']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['tier']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
```

I have this code and it gets data from the database by comparing the 2 tables. So for example the one in order table is 5,6,2,1,4,3. So when the query compares the 2 tables it checks for 5 then 6 then 2 and so on. When the results come out, the results become sorted and the output becomes 1,2,3,4,5,6 but I want to output it in the order how I input it. It is somehow auto sorting. Is it possible to disable that?

Comment: Is there a date field in either table that you could use in: `ORDER BY field ASC`

Comment: I dont have a date field but that's a good idea. Is it possible to get the time of the input?

Comment: there is no implicit ordering in sql, though some databases do allow it. if you want to force an ordering on your results, you generally need to explicitly add it, e.g. `order by some_relevant_field`.

Comment: @jeeeee Only if you've stored that value in your table at the time of insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly specify a sort order with the user of `ORDER BY`. Mysql and other databases does not provide any guarantee about the order in what the data is returned.

If you have a table that hasn't had many deletes and updates, the order is likely the order that you inserted. But no guarantee. So use `ORDER BY`

Comment: I would like to add to this that your best option is to either add a `date/datetime` column or order by `id` descending.

Comment: I added a datetime and it worked perfectly thank you very much!